# Drupal 7: cannot override in template.php

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I try to override theme_menu_tree in drupal 7.

My function (shown below) is very simple, but it seems drupal skips it, even put a "die" there. I have clear the cache afterward, but it is no use.

Has anyone successfully override a function in template.php?

```
function unitheme_menu_tree($variables) {
    die("die!");
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me...are you positive the theme is called `unitheme`, is the enabled theme, and that you've cleared the theme registry cache after implementing the hook?

Comment: I reinstall drupal + modules (It took a while to do so). It seems fixing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just a friendly tip, you should pass the variable by reference with the & operator, the menu tree is a rather costly loop.

```
function unitheme_menu_tree(&$variables) {
}
```